# How to get UILabel Tags in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I am creating labels dynamically from `NSMutableArray`.While creating labels I have set tags for each label. I have one `NSMutableArray` named `wordArray`. Now, I want to check my string is available in wordArray or not,
I can check this using :

```
[wordArray containsObject:wordStr];
```

For creating labels dynamically :

```
UILabel *wordLabl;
int tagValue3 = 1;
for (int iloop = 0; iloop < [wordArray count]; iloop++)
{

     wordLabl = [self addwordLabelRect:CGRectMake(80 * iloop + 20, 420 , 100,      20)andTag:tagValue3];//30 + 35 30 * iloop+
     [self.view addSubview:wordLabl];
     tagValue3 += 1;
}

-(UILabel *)addwordLabelRect:(CGRect)rect andTag:(int)integerValue
{
wordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
wordLabel.frame = rect;
wordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
wordLabel.tag = integerValue;
wordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
wordLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
wordLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[wordArray objectAtIndex:integerValue - 1]];
wordLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
wordLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return wordLabel;
}
```

Using above code I am creating labels and Tags.
But,If `wordArray` contains the string I want to change the `textColor` of that label.I think this can be done using Tag , but how can I get the tag value of the label.

Comment: what you can do is store those labels tag in an array and then , get the label based on that tag. you can easily do it my friend....

Comment: Do you store created `UILabels` in `NSMutableArray`? Show your code

Comment: If you provide your code, will help to provide precise solutions

Comment: @Andrey Gordeev and Syed Absar I have Edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I overlooked you code... You just need to add following lines where you want to access your appropriate label:

```
if([wordArray containsObject:wordStr])
{
UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:([wordArray indexOfObject:wordStr] - 1)];//since u started tag assignment from 1
label.textcolor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing something like that to set the tags ?

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [wordArray count]; ++i) {
    UILabel * label;
    // setup your label...
    [label setTag:i];
    [yourView addSubview:label];
}
```

If so, just do :

```
NSUInteger index = [wordArray indexOfObject:wordStr];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
    UILabel * label = [yourView viewWithTag:index];
    // do whatever you want with your label
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: What if `yourView` has multiple objects with the same tag? Which one is returned? What if the view that is returned isn't a `UILabel` how does your code handle this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get UILabel from its Tag.
you can use following loop

```
int i=0;
for (NSObject *view in self.View.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
    {
      label = (UILabel *)[[self view] viewWithTag:wordArray[i]];
        NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
       //here you get your label
    }
  i++;
}
```